# local server error in divio app installation django-cms

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms, failed-installation, divio

I am trying to install DIVIO app , 
and when I try to set it up this is the error i received:

```
New version 3.3.2 is available. Type `divio version` to show information about upgrading.
Usage: divio project setup [OPTIONS] SLUG

Error: Invalid value for "-p" / "--path": Path "." is not writable...
```

I am running windows 7 and docker terminal is already running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Divio application is trying to write some files, but doesn't have permission to. This issue is generally caused when your Divio projects are not located within your user's filespace.

Make sure that in the Divio application settings your projects will be somewhere within your home folder.